# Laplaces equation with Legengre polynomials

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-series

Consider the following question

[image]

Following the hint, I got
$$
\Phi (r, \theta) =
\begin{cases}
a_n r^n P_n(\cos \theta) \quad r>1 \
b_n r^{-(n+1)} P_n (\cos \theta) \quad r>1.
\end{cases}
$$
I tried to apply the initial condition and I got
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P_n (\cos \theta) ((-n-1)b_n -n a_n)= V \cos \theta^2
$$

However, I am not sure what to do now. I know that I can integrate both sides by

$$
\int P_k (\cos \theta) \cdot \big[\quad\big] \; d\theta,
$$
but integrating

$$
\int P_k (\cos \theta) \cos ^2 \theta \; d \theta
$$
has not been covered in my course.

Could someone clarify what is the intended way for this problem?

Comment: Hint: $\cos^2\theta$ can be written in terms of $P_n(\cos\theta)$. Then use orthogonality.

Comment: Hi @eyeballfrog. Do I need to find $P_1$ and $P_0$ and solve for $\cos ^2$?

Comment: Learn the correct spelling: Laplaces -> Laplace, Legengre -> Legendre...